# Changing FS in awk to match anything that isn't a file path

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I'm trying to extract file paths from a program's output using awk. This is my first time using awk, I heard it was good for this kind of thing, so I hit the GNU manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html (awk symlinks to gawk on my machine)

I'm trying to alter FS to make the separator match anything that isn't a file path. I tried this out for a situation where I hardcoded 2 file paths in the input:

```
awk -F '[^(\\/.)*]' '{print $1; print $2}'
```

I figured that `[^(\\/.)*]` would set FS to match any text that doesn't match a file path. I thought the parentheses would prevent the regex from being considered individual characters e.g. `[^abcd]`. And the paths can be as long as they want, hence the asterisk. This did not work.

I have input that looks something like this:

`a whole bunch of random garbage oooh! a file /opt/dir/file and perhaps some more garbage and another file! /usr/local/bin`

I expect output like this:

```
/opt/dir/file
/usr/local/bin
```

I'll be capturing this expected output in a Bash variable.

Does anyone know how to do this correctly? It would also help if this would be correct if I passed the `--posix` command. Note: There can be an arbitrary number of file paths stored amongst the junk.

Comment: How do you distinguish between file paths and other junk? What exactly is the pattern you're looking for?

Comment: @melpomene The file paths will all be of the form `/dir1/dir2/dir3/file`. The junk is irrelevant information that is output by a program, that can include version numbers, and such, but never includes anything that can look like a file path, unless it does in fact print a file path. My objective was to make the junk the field separator, so I can iterate over the fields and print them, or do something with them.

Comment: Be more specific. What exactly are the characters that can appear in e.g. "dir1"? Apparently you don't allow spaces or `#` (why not?), but what else?

Comment: @melpomene I'm not certain I understand. I thought the `.` matched anything.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "looks like a file path". `a whole bunch of random garbage oooh! a file ` is a valid directory name. You think it doesn't look like a file path, but I do (and unix agrees). So the best thing you can do is match some subset of valid directory names, and I'm trying to figure out what exactly this subset is.

Comment: If you want the pattern to match between zero and unlimited times the asterisk (quantifier) needs to be placed outside of the square brackets (eg. `[ ... ]*`).

Comment: @melpomene All paths start at root, hence `/dir1/dir2/dir3/file` would be a path, but `garbage out put that isnt a file path /dir1/dir2/dir3/file some more crap /dir1/dir2/dir3/file2` contains only two file paths. Everything that doesnt match an arbirarily long sequence of `/` with text between them isn't a path. In retrospect, the path would end with whitespace, so `/dir1/dir2/dir3/file `

Comment: Does it have to be awk? My first instinct would be to do this with perl.

Comment: @melpomene The system this will be deployed on will not have perl.

Comment: A regular expression character class `[...]` cannot contain nested regular expressions. It is a notation for multiple possibilities for matching exactly one character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use grep when you want to extract specific patterns out of some text. To find all words containing a slash:

```
grep -o '[^[:blank:]]*/[^[:blank:]]*'
```

A bit easier to read with GNU grep's pcre patterns:

```
grep -oP '\S*/\S*'
```

where `\S` is the complement of `\s` (whitespace)

Comment: Whitespace in filenames is perfectly valid. This answer will not properly match a filename containing a space/tab/newline/etc. However, I suspect such a filename is not expected in your output.

Comment: So both solutions are matching an arbitrary amount of non-whitespace (the uses a pre-defined character class, right?), a literal slash, then an arbitrary amount of non-whitespace? You are correct, the filenames will not have whitespace. Something I should have mentioned :/ Why is no escaping of the slash necessary?

Comment: As I commented on James' answer, the slash is not a special character in a regular expression. Special characters include `.`,`*`,`+`,`[` and so on. Slashes only need attention in a language like sed where the "search and replace" command uses slashes (by default) as the delimiter.

Comment: Thanks! I thought there might a diff between what grep and awk take, but it occurs to me that the awk manual might have stated something about regex similarities between the two.

Comment: Start with your `regex(7)` man page. However, frustratingly, different tools use different flavours of regular expressions.

Comment: I'm new to using regexs, I'm trying to modify some stuff at my internship, so this is definitely something I need to learn. I'll hit up the manpage

Comment: I applaud you for taking this approach to learning. There's tons of good info here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info

Comment: @Ungeheuer grep is just one of many tools that use regexps so you shouldn't expect to see the awk manual discuss the similarities/difference between it's regexps and greps regexps any more than any other tools regexps. Also if you were writing a book on awk you wouldn't want to have to update it when grep or sed or perl or ruby or python or any other tool updated its regexp format and/or options that cause it to use different formats (e.g. grep vs grep -E vs grep -P)

Answer (score 3):

Using GNU awk and [`RT`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Auto_002dset.html#Auto_002dset)<sup>†</sup>:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="([^ ]*/[^ ]*)+"}{print RT}' file
/opt/dir/file
/usr/local/bin
[here be a nasty empty line]
```

<sup>†</sup> `RT #` The input text that matched the text denoted by `RS`, the record separator. It is set every time a record is read.

Edit: You could also use GNU awk's `split` with the `seps` (notice `\/` since `/...\/.../`):

```
$ awk ' {
    split($0,a,/([^ ]*\/[^ ]*)+/,seps)
    for(i in seps)
        print seps[i]
}' file
/opt/dir/file
/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: RS is the record separator, but what is RT? I don't see it under the Predefined Variables section. And why did you change the record separator?  I don't entirely understand the regex. It matches things that start with anything but a space, an arbitrary number of times, and a forward slash, which I don't recognize from the manual, then again matching anything that isn't a space an arbitrary number of times.

Comment: Quite a cool solution. Instead of making the garbage the FS, make the desired text the RS. What does that slash in the middle mean though? It is interpreted as a literal slash? I thought that would have to be escaped?

Comment: Yeah, it's literal in this case. If it was escaped, it would produce: `awk: cmd. line:1: warning: escape sequence '\/' treated as plain '/'`.

Comment: @Ungeheuer, a plain slash has no special meaning in a regular expression. For the sed command `s/re/text/`, then yes the slash would have to be escaped to not be seen as a command delimiter, but not here.

Comment: @James change `{print RT}` to `RT{print RT}` to avoid said "nasty empty line". You should really be using `\S` or `[^[:space:]]` instead of `[^ ]` in the regexps though or it'll fail when there's tabs between file paths.

Comment: @EdMorton That `RT{print RT}` doesn't work for me, I still get the "nasty" one.

Comment: Oh yeah, because the last newline is attached to the last file name. You;'d need to add a `|\n` to RS or `sub(/\n$/,"")` before the print.